# How does wpa_supplicant differ from the Linux (say Debian) version

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-direct, wpa-supplicant

**What are the major differences between `wpa_supplicant` found on a Debian Linux distribution and that `wpa_supplicant` found on android?**

PS: please apology if the question is too generic

Answer (score 0):

In Android, **wpa_supplicant** deamon, **wpa_cli** and **libwpa_client** library are generated from wpa_supplicant external project found in [aosp_root/external/wpa_supplicant](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/wpa_supplicant/+/master); being in the "external" folder means that it was taken as is from another project (means wasn't *Androidized* in any way). so I think there are no differeneces at all.

Also the [README](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/wpa_supplicant/+/master/) file found in the project says that it can work on all distros based on linux kernel.

Comment: Can you then explain why wpa keys from Android don't work on Debian? (`WRONG_KEY`)